# What will happen if we do entire Thread functionality in start method instead of run method?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

What will happen if we do entire Thread functionality in start method instead of run method?Below code runs in same way as it would have run if I added code in run method..

```
   public class RunMethodTest extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Abc abc=new Abc();
        abc.start();
    }
}

class Abc extends Thread
{
    @Override
    public synchronized void start() {
        super.start();
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Thread" + " " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Below code runs in same way as it would have run if I added code in run method" - No, it does not. It will run in the method that you call `start()` from, instead of in a separate thread.

Comment: It will execute synchronously.

Comment: @Jesper It will not create separate thread?..AFAIK since I am calling start() separate thread is created

Comment: @AndyTurner run method is asynchronous..whats advantage of tht?

Comment: You are calling `super.start()` which starts a thread, but the logic will not magically run in that thread. Since you put the logic in your own `start()` method, it will run in the thread that calls the `start()` method. Just like any other method.

Comment: Call `Thread.getCurrentThread()` and call its `getId()` method in your calling code and in your start method to see what thread you are in. You will see that you are not in a new thread.  `System.out.println("id: " + Thread.getCurrentThread().getId());`

Comment: @varmashrivastava unless you are planning to overwrite the default behaviour of thread, there is no reason what-so-ever you should ever extend the Thread class.

Comment: @varmashrivastava the run method isn't intrinsically asynchronous: it's just a plain old method. But the magic internals of `Thread.start` (in the base class) invoke it asynchronously.

Comment: Oops, that should be `Thread.currentThread().getId()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test it: have your code tell you which thread it is being called in by

1. Getting the current thread via `Thread.currentThread()`
2. And then getting the current thread's id and name via `getId()` and `getName()`

```
public class ThreadTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
        System.out.printf("Main, Which Thread: %s, %d%n", 
                currentThread.getName(), 
                currentThread.getId());

        Abc abc = new Abc();
        abc.start();
    }
}
```

```
class Abc extends Thread {
    @Override
    public synchronized void start() {
        super.start();

        Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
        System.out.printf("Start, Which Thread: %s, %d%n", 
                currentThread.getName(), 
                currentThread.getId());

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Thread" + " " + i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();

        Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
        System.out.printf("Run, Which Thread: %s, %d%n", 
                currentThread.getName(), 
                currentThread.getId());
    }
}
```

For me this returns:

```
Main, Which Thread: main, 1
Start, Which Thread: main, 1
Run, Which Thread: Thread-0, 9
Thread 0
Thread 1
Thread 2
Thread 3
....
```

Which proves that your Abc's start method is (as expected) being called in the same thread as the calling code and not in a new thread, and that only code within the `run()` method is being called within a new thread. As has been noted above though, you almost never need to or want to extend Thread but rather implement Runnable or Callable.